# iOS NSURLSessionConfiguration in Amazon S3 Upload- SSL error

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nsurlsession

I am building an iOS application which uploads bunch of files to Amazon S3 in the background- I am making use of the `NSURLSession` in conjunction with the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` for this and this seems to be working well. The files are being uploaded as single putObjects

However strangely though I am faced with an issue when I try to upload say 50 images some them mostly towards the end gets an error as follows;

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200` "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

Can this may due to the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` properties I have set up ? Here is my code;

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *myConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:sessionIdentifier];
        [myConfig setTimeoutIntervalForResource:2400];
        [myConfig setTimeoutIntervalForRequest:2400];
        myConfig.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
```

In this scenario I have played out a bit with `timeoutIntervalForRequest` and `timeoutIntervalForResource` values but that didn't seem to fix it. Could anyone suggest the optimum values for these 2?

Also I am not using the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` which I understand as that which specifies the number of concurrent operations. What do you think I should set this value provided pretty good network conditions exist? Ive also not used `HTTPShouldUsePipelining`

Or is this something that has nothing to do with `NSURLSession` but with the AWS part. I m using the 1.7 Version . Perhaps AWS maintainers over here could help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue after building some older apps for iOS9.  According to Apple's web site...

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016240-CH1-SW3

"Certificates must be signed using a SHA256 or greater signature"

I ran into this issue while using a server leveraging a SHA-1 with RSA Encryption which is not sufficient.

Testing on a server that had SHA-256 with RSA Encryption worked without the "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" work-around.

You have two options from here:

1. You can add *.yoursite.com to the whitelist in the plist instead
   of "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads".
2. Your IT team can upgrade the server to a SHA256 signature.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are building for iOS 9.0 or later, there's a new feature introduced called App Transport Security that you need to setup for your S3 uploads to work.

The AWS Mobile iOS SDK blog has a [post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2QM69ZE6BGTYX/Preparing-Your-Apps-for-iOS-9) addressing this new feature and the changes you need to make.

As an aside, unless you have compelling reasons to manually setup these NSURLSessions, I recommend using the [aws-sdk-ios](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) to do the uploads for you.